# Django TextField does not enforce blank=False

Tags: django, django-models

I can't get `django.db.models.TextField(blank=False)` to enforce non-blank. It seems to ignore the constraint and only enforces not-null.

Example:

```
import django.core.exception
import django.db.models
import unittest

class Mymodel(django.db.models.Model):
    id = django.db.models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    text = django.db.models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)

with self.assertRaises(django.core.exception.ValidationError):
    Mymodel.objects.create()   # <--- should raise validation exception
```

The above code creates a new `Mymodel` instance with the `text` field set to a blank string, but instead it should raise a `ValidationError`

Details: python 3.8.5, django 3.1, postgresql 12.4

Comment: afaik `blank` is relevant only for form (ModelForm) validation

Comment: Can you try `required=True`

Comment: `required` is not a valid field option in django 3.1 (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#field-options)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call **`full_clean()`** method

```
from django.core import exceptions

class TestTextFieldError(TestCase):
    def test_error(self):
        with self.assertRaises(exceptions.ValidationError):
            instance = Mymodel()
            instance.full_clean()
```

Answer (score -1):

> text = django.db.models.TextField(blank=False, null=False, default="")

try setting default

Comment: Hello ! Would that changes anything ? If so would you explain what are the effects of this modification ?